# MySQL sort of union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to 3 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_article`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Persons_Articles :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons_Articles` (
  `id_article` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_person` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `role` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_article`,`id_person`,`role`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Persons:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

INSERT INTO Articles VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'B');
INSERT INTO Persons_Articles VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Persons_Articles VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, 'Mick', 'Jagger', 'Mick Jagger');
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (2, 'Keith', 'Richards', 'Keith Richards');
```

I look for a query which can return the article with (fullname = 'Mick Jagger' AND role = 1) AND (fullname = 'Keith Richards' AND role = 2)

Any ideas ?

Comment: @Torrezzzz, your comment suggests an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons P
INNER JOIN Persons_Articles PA ON PA.id_person = P.id
INNER JOIN Articles A ON A.id = PA.id_article
WHERE (P.fullname = 'Mick Jagger' AND PA.role = 1) OR (P.fullname = 'Keith Richards' AND PA.role = 2)
```

Comment: This query seems to work... You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ad0e/2

Comment: I think the OP wanted the article that has both those people in their respective roles, not either.

Comment: @Ipg Cheers for the fiddle

Comment: That does give you both people in their respective roles.  Explain how it doesn't?

Comment: Nope it returns articles with either Mick in role 1 OR Keith in role 2.. not both Mick in role 1 AND Keith in role 2. You can tell by the `OR` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @user1686061 Was there a problem with my answer?

Comment: Did you run the fiddle? It gives you two records.

Comment: Yes, OP wants **one** record, **the** article with both Keith **and** Mick in their respective roles.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you cannot have have a duplicate (name and role) for an article:

```
  SELECT a.*
    FROM articles a
    JOIN persons_articles pa
      ON pa.id_article = a.id
    JOIN persons p
      ON pa.id_person = p.id
     AND ((p.fullname = 'Mick Jagger' AND pa.role = 1) OR (p.fullname = 'Keith Richards' AND pa.role = 2))
GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

**UPDATE**

As a side note, I would never store the fullname in the database.. it leads to more work with `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s and if you are not careful, you can end up with mismatched names. Although it is slightly more work, you can always `CONCAT()` the names if need be.

Comment: Just tried it with my real tables (70000 articles, 100000 persons...). No results

Comment: the firstname and the lastname are stored since the beginning:-)

Comment: @user1686061 Then there must be something wrong with what you wrote.. it works on the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ad0e/2). Did you match the number at the end of the `HAVING` to the number of conditions in the `COUNT`?

Comment: @user1686061 I don't have a problem with the first and last names, just the full name. Besides, even if it has been there since the beginning.. doesn't mean it's a good idea! :)

Comment: Yes I matched it. I re wrote the query for my DB. And here it is : SELECT a.*
    FROM Articles_Description a
    JOIN Persons_Articles pa ON pa.id_article_desc = a.Id_Article_Desc
    JOIN Persons p ON pa.id_person = p.id
  HAVING COUNT(
   (p.fullname2 LIKE '%Banderas%' AND pa.role = 2) 
 OR (p.fullname2 LIKE '%Madonna%' AND pa.role = 2)) = 2

Comment: @Ameoba, you are checking `pa.role = 2` in each condition.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Here is the principle : it's a search engine on a DVD/BRay DB. The user must choose in his search 2 or more people. These people each have one role: for example, we look for the movies directed (role 1) by Steven Spielberg with Harrison as an actor (role 2).

Comment: @Amoeba That all looks correct, and this approach will work. If you are having trouble with not getting the expected results, I would suggest checking each condition in turn to make sure it is actually present in your data in the way you expect it is.

Comment: Hi. I made a new fiddle for my tests. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73507/3 - The number at the end of the count must match (apparently) the total number of rows in the persons_articles table.

Comment: @Amoeba, woops, sorry you are totally correct see updated answer.

Comment: I made a mistake. With this fiddle, same results... But not the same values in Persons_Articles : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b82ab/1 And if I change the 5 by a 2 at the end of the query, no results ... Aaaarrrghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh :-(

Comment: @Amoeba, check my final updated answer, the other one wasn't entirely correct (it was returning articles 1 and 4 or the fiddle even though in 4 Keith was in the wrong role).. and I think by putting the conditions in the JOIN you get a faster response.

Comment: I check it, I try it in my PMA, and it works ! I have the results we want. Many thanks Arth !